# exporting list of types from xsd file

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, xsd

I need to compare the lists of types included in various `xsd` files.  There are hundreds of types, so I would like to get the names of the types into text format so that I can compare lists of several hundred elements using other software.  Is there an easy, free tool for extracting just the names of all the types in an `xsd` file?

I am using `eclipse` and `java`.  The `eclipse xsd design view` shows the names of types but does not let you extract the names into the windows clipboard in text format for use in other applications.

Comment: Are you looking for types *declared* in your XSD, or types *used* therein?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I am looking for types declared in the file because that would be simpler to keep track of in this case.  The types used therein should take care of themselves in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XSLT transform is just the tool for this job.  The stylesheet might look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="xsd:simpleType">
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="xsd:complexType">
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You could even amend that to indicate which types are simple and which complex.

You could process your XSD using that stylesheet via a command-line processor such as `xsltproc`, or it would be pretty easy to write your own wrapper around Java's built-in XSLT engine to do the same job.

Comment: +1 and thank you for looking into this.  I am going to wait to review this until I have some time to do some research on the web about the concepts. For the immediate problem, I just ended up opening two windows in eclipse so I could view the lists of types in xsd design view side by side by aligning the windows.  But your approach looks more sophisticated, so I will read up on it eagerly later.